# jQuery height interpreted differently in Chrome & Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a some list items and I need to apply the height of the second item to all other sibling items starting from the third to the last, so I wrote this code:

```
var boxHeight = $('.boxes-list li:eq(1)').height();
$('.boxes-list li:gt(1)').height(boxHeight);
```

This works perfectly in Chrome. If I add a `console.log(boxHeight);` after the first line, it prints `127` in the Chrome console. However, when I go to Safari, the console.log statement prints `187` and does not show the height correctly in the DOM. I don't have any padding, margin, or border on those li elements but I still tried innerHeight and outerHeight to no avail.

Basically, the height method is being differently interpreted in Chrome and Safari. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you used something like https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ first?.

Comment: @Keith, yes I used normalize.css.

Comment: Browsers by nature often have inconsistency's.  But after normalize.css I wouldn't expect 60px difference.   It might help more if you make a quick Snippet.  (a small reproducible problem)